# Push dynamically added html list item into last array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can i push html into the last array. I was trying to add an item and supposed be add instantly into list array. The cod is working except I'm struggling to add new list into last array.

```
   function addItem(id,name){

        const array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('categories'));

              array.push({
             name: name,
             id:id,
      }); 

     //<li>{name}</li> push this into last array

     localStorage.setItem('categories',JSON.stringify(array));
    }


    {categories.map(function(item, key){
             return <div> 
             <ul>
                <li>item.name</li>
              </ul>
            <button onClick={() => addItem(item.id,'value name')}>Add</button>
               </div>
      })}
```

Comment: Can you post a complete example? What are you expecting and what about this code doesn't produce the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something looks wrong in your example. I have added a complete exampl. You can maintain localStorage and State both. I hope this example helps you.

You mistake is that while adding new item you are pushing it to localStoage due to which react dom does not get rerendered. You have to update the value of state for that.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      categories: [
        {
          name: "Hello",
          id: 1
        },
        {
          name: "World",
          id: 2
        }
      ]
    };
    this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
    this.SaveToLocalStorage = this.SaveToLocalStorage.bind(this);
  }

  SaveToLocalStorage() {
    const categories = this.state.categories;
    localStorage.setItem("categories", JSON.stringify(categories));
  }

  addItem(id, name) {
    const categories = this.state.categories;
    categories.push({
      name: name,
      id: id
    });
    this.setState({ categories });
    //localStorage.setItem("categories", JSON.stringify(categories));
  }

  render() {
    let categories = this.state.categories;
    const test = categories.map(item => (
      <div key={item.id}>
        <li>{item.name}</li>
      </div>
    ));
    return (
      <div>
        {test}
        <button onClick={() => this.addItem(Date.now(), "Item")}>
          Click to Add More
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => this.SaveToLocalStorage()}>
          Save To LocalStorage{" "}
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are asking for. You just need to set it to state and re-render it when ever you are trying to add an element to list/array. I don't know why you are setting it to local storage but you can do it from state directly if your intention is to just store the previous array for future additions.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class App extends Component {
  state = {};
  constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state={
          arr = []
      }
  }
  addItem(id, name) {
    const array = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("categories"));
    array.push({
      name: name,
      id: id
    });
    //<li>{name}</li> push this into last array
    localStorage.setItem("categories", JSON.stringify(array));
    this.setState({arr:array});
  }
  renderList = () => {
      return this.state.array.map(function(item, key) {
        return (
          <div>
            <ul>
              <li>item.name</li>
            </ul>
            <button onClick={() => addItem(item.id, "value name")}>Add</button>
          </div>
        );
      });
  };
  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderList()}</div>;
  }
}

export default App;
```